# If else ladder in QBasic

Tags: if-statement, qbasic

My QBasic code for computing discount is below:

```
CLS
INPUT "ENTER BILL AMOUNT";AMT
IF AMT <= 6000 THEN
    DISCOUNT = 0
ELSEIF AMT > 6000 AND AMT <= 15000 THEN
    DISCOUNT = 0.2 * AMT
ELSEIF AMT > 15000 AND AMT <= 50000 THEN
    DISCOUNT = 0.3 * AMT
ELSEIF AMT > 50000 AND AMT <= 100000 THEN
    DISCOUNT = 0.4 * AMT
ELSEIF AMT > 100000 AND AMT<= 200000 THEN
    DISCOUNT = 0.5 * AMT
ELSEIF AMT > 200000 AND AMT <= 1000000 THEN
    DISCOUNT = 0.6 * AMT
ELSE
    DISCOUNT = 0.7 * AMT
END IF
NET = AMT - DISCOUNT
PRINT "THE BILL AMOUNT IS:"; NET
END
```

However, I get an error on Line 50 (Line 5 of program) while running the program, though I can't find any syntax errors in the program.

Comment: What error? Why QBasic?

Comment: I think QBasic doesn't have `else if`, it should be `elseif` instead.

Comment: I need to code in Qbasic.

Comment: You **need** to code in QBasic like I need to lose both my arms.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: On which platform do you run QBasic nowadays?

Comment: The '90 have called and they want their QBasic back :-)

Comment: Is it just for the fun of being th 42's question tagged qbasic ever ?

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax in QBasic is [`ELSEIF`](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/QBasic/chapter18/bc18_11.html) instead of `ELSE IF` (note that the two words are written as one, without a space).

Comment: Then it's finally time you tell us _what_ error QBasic is reporting.

Answer (score 2):

You should replace ELSE IF by ELSEIF.

```
CLS
INPUT "ENTER BILL AMOUNT"; AMT
IF AMT <= 6000 THEN
    DISCOUNT = 0
ELSEIF AMT > 6000 AND AMT <= 15000 THEN
    DISCOUNT = 0.2 * AMT
ELSEIF AMT > 15000 AND AMT <= 50000 THEN
    DISCOUNT = 0.3 * AMT
ELSEIF AMT > 50000 AND AMT <= 100000 THEN
    DISCOUNT = 0.4 * AMT
ELSEIF AMT >100000 AND AMT <= 200000 THEN
    DISCOUNT = 0.5 * AMT
ELSEIF AMT > 200000 AND AMT <= 1000000 THEN
    DISCOUNT = 0.6 * AMT
ELSE
    DISCOUNT = 0.7 * AMT
END IF
NET = AMT - DISCOUNT
PRINT "THE BILL AMOUNT IS:" NET
END
```

alternatively, if you really want to make a "LADDER" as your title suggest, you should :

```
CLS
INPUT "ENTER BILL AMOUNT";AMT
IF AMT <=6000 THEN
    DISCOUNT = 0
ELSE 
    IF AMT > 6000 AND AMT <= 15000 THEN
        DISCOUNT =0.2 * AMT
    ELSE 
        IF AMT > 15000 AND AMT <= 50000 THEN
            DISCOUNT =0.3*AMT
        ELSE 
            IF AMT >50000 AND AMT<=100000 THEN
                DISCOUNT =0.4*AMT
            ELSE 
                IF AMT >100000 AND AMT<=200000 THEN
                    DISCOUNT =0.5*AMT
                ELSE 
                    IF AMT >200000 AND AMT<=1000000 THEN
                        DISCOUNT =0.6*AMT
                    ELSE
                        DISCOUNT =0.7*AMT
                    END IF
                END IF
            END IF
        END IF
    END IF
END IF
NET=AMT - DISCOUNT
PRINT "THE BILL AMOUNT IS:"NET
END
```

Comment: Boy, _please_, indentation!

Comment: I *do* agree with indentation ... but I had to respect the asker's coding style (even if I don't like it).

Answer (score 2):

Below is a solution without any ELSEs:

```
CLS
INPUT "ENTER BILL AMOUNT BEFORE DISCOUNT"; AMT
DISCOUNT = 0.7
IF AMT <= 1000000 THEN DISCOUNT = 0.6
IF AMT <= 200000 THEN DISCOUNT = 0.5
IF AMT <= 100000 THEN DISCOUNT = 0.4
IF AMT <= 50000 THEN DISCOUNT = 0.3
IF AMT <= 15000 THEN DISCOUNT = 0.2
IF AMT <= 6000 THEN DISCOUNT = 0
DISCOUNT = DISCOUNT * AMT
NET = AMT - DISCOUNT
PRINT "THE BILL AMOUNT IS:"; NET
END
```

Comment: Someone should have hinted him at the correct syntax (http://chortle.ccsu.edu/QBasic/chapter18/bc18_11.html). And someone should let him know that giving the biggest discount on all items he did not think about, is not the best solution. that way your answer is only second best.

Answer (score 0):

This solves the ladder by making the discount and amount more readable.

```
CLS
INPUT "ENTER BILL AMOUNT"; AMT
SELECT CASE AMT
    CASE IS <= 6000
        DISCOUNT = 0
    CASE 6000 TO 15000
        DISCOUNT = 0.2 * AMT
    CASE 15000 TO 50000
        DISCOUNT = 0.3 * AMT
    CASE 50000 TO 100000
        DISCOUNT = 0.4 * AMT
    CASE 100000 TO 200000
        DISCOUNT = 0.5 * AMT
    CASE 200000 TO 1000000
        DISCOUNT = 0.6 * AMT
    CASE ELSE
        DISCOUNT = 0.7 * AMT
END SELECT
NET = AMT - DISCOUNT
PRINT "THE BILL AMOUNT IS:"; NET
END
```